# close the browser tab, opened by opn in node js

Tags: node.js, node-horseman

I'm using the **opn** package to open a url in my browser. I need to close that window after some time from the node service. How do I achieve that using opn?

I tried with **node-horseman**. I can't use that more than once, however. If I try, I get an issue in the second horseman like

```
Unhandled rejection HeadlessError: Phantom Process died
```

I need to close the opened windows through the service. How do I solve this? Can anyone help me out?

And my horseman code is,

```
horseMan
    .open('http://localhost:4000/next?port=3000')
    .log('Checking the next course...')
    .close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @prabha, did you ever figure this out? I'd like to know too.

Comment: Hi @prabha - if you've figured this out, could you let us know? I'm stuck too.
I also spell-checked and restructured your question to make it understandable to english-readers. If I have changed anything drastic, feel free to undo my changes,

Comment: @mcheah, I hope you didn't have issue with this till now. Sorry for the late response. Instead of opening the window, I use request module to get the result which I expect. And I didn't solved it coz of module change.

Comment: Thanks @Raisus, I updated :-).